# python-opencv draw bounding box with pixel value

Tags: bounding-box, opencv, python

I want to draw bounding box in an image with these given values :

`{"detection_classes": ["KATSUWONUS_PELAMIS", "PERSON"], "detection_boxes": [["605.20154", "61.680183", "945.9218", "988.8461"], ["159.51956", "435.82422", "1213.0", "917.4274"]], "detection_scores": ["0.9615494", "0.99781716"]}`

the detection boxes value above is in **pixels**

the first `[["605.20154", "61.680183", "945.9218", "988.8461"]` is the fish bounding box value

and `["159.51956", "435.82422", "1213.0", "917.4274"]]` is the person bounding box value

and this is the original
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XtDt.jpg)

I want to use `cv.rectangle` but the parameter of this function are arrays

Is there any alternative? I use python 3.7.5 and opencv4.x

Thankyou in advance

Comment: What do the 4 coordinate values represent? Are they top left x and y and bottom right x and y?  If so, then convert them to integers and use cv2.rectangle(image, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), color, thickness).

Comment: you can use the int() function to parse string to int. Then create tuples of the int values and pass that in as parameters

Comment: yes, the 4 coordinate values represent the x1, y1, x2 dan y2. So I can get the Width = y2-y1 and height = x2 - x1